# Custom archive format File Reading

Tags: c#, c++, file, visual-c++

**C#.NET 4.0**

I'm having an interesting problem here with reading a custom file archive format.  In C#, I wrote a program that creates an archive header (some overhead info about the archive as a whole, number of files, those kinds of things).  It then takes an input file to be stored, reads and bytes, and then writes some overhead about the file (filename, type, size and such) and then the actual file data.  I can also extract files from the archive through this program.  To test it, I stored a png image and extracted it by reading the filesize from the overhead and then allocating an array of bytes of that size, pulled the filedata into that array, and then wrote it with a streamwriter.  No big deal, worked fine.  Now, we go to the C++ side...

**C++**

My C++ program needs to read the filedata in, determine the filetype, and then pass it off to the appropriate processing class.  The processing classes were giving errors, which they shouldn't have.  So I decided to write the filedata out fro the C++ program after reading it using fwrite(), and the resulting file appears to be damaged?  In a nutshell, this is the code being used to read the file...

```
unsigned char * data = 0;
char temp = 0;
__int64 fileSize = 0;
fread(&fileSize, sizeof(__int64), 1, _fileHandle);
data = new unsigned char[fileSize];

for (__int64 i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
{
    fread(&temp, 1, 1, _fileHandle);
    data[i] = temp;
}
```

(I'm at work right now, so I just wrote this from memory.  However, I'm 99% positive it's accurate to my code at home.  I'm also not concerned with non MS Standards at the moment, so please bear with the __int64.)

I haven't gone through all 300 something thousand bytes to determine if everything is consistent, but the first 20 or so bytes that I looked at appear to be correct.  I don't exactly see why there is a problem.  Is there something funny about fread()?  I also to double check the file in the archive, removed all the archive overhead and saved just the image data to a new png image with notepad, which worked fine.

Should I be reading this differently?  Is there something wrong with using fread() to read in this data?

Comment: Well, this is somewhat inefficient (why not `fread(data, 1, fileSize, _fileHandle)` rather than the loop?), but looks ok.  However, you should check the return value from `fread` to ensure that it's really reading as much as you asked for.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I originally used fread how you suggested, but I changed to the loop to see if the error changed at all.  Needless to say, it didn't.

Comment: Ok, describe 'damaged'. Is the C++ result larger, smaller, or does it just have different bytes somewhere? Checking the return of fread() against fileSize could have told you something.

Comment: You do not show how the _fileHandle is created. Does it specify 'binary'?

Comment: @Henk.  The filesize result is the same.  I really can't tell what's damanged because the output appears the same as the input.  As for thee _fileHandle creation, I can't remember off hand..I probably specified "rb", but I'll have to double check that for you when I get home.

Comment: If input and output are the same the problem is solved. Otherwise use a diff tool.

Comment: @Henk Can you suggest any tools to compare the input and output? I don't have one currently, and again, checking 300 something thousand bytes in notepad++ would be ridiculous. The problem is also not solved because I cannot open the output in an image viewer. So somewhere in the output, there must be a problem.

Comment: Another thing to think about is that you might have a symmetric bug in your C# code, so that the binary data is not exactly what you think it should be. So going by hand through the file with a good hexeditor might be useful.

Comment: @MGZero: [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is a hex editor I like a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the first `n` bytes appear to be correct, did you by chance forget to open the file in binary mode (`"rb"`)? If you didn't then it's helpfully converting any sequences of `\r\n` into `\n` for you which would obviously not be what you want.

Since this question is tagged C++ did you consider using the canonical C++ approach of iostreams rather than the somewhat antiquated `FILE*` streams from C?

Comment: I'll double check the read mode when I get home.  If that doesn't give anything, I'll go for the iostreams approach.

Comment: Ok, the issue was the test writer was not in binary mode...unfortunately, this does not fix the issue of my processing classes not working.  Looks like I'll be spending my night coding :)